# Complex 'AND' Django Queries

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, django-database

I'm trying to do the equivalent of this SQL query:

```
"SELECT * FROM something WHERE ((something >= something AND something <= something) AND(something >= something AND something <= something))"
```

And I can't quite figure it out.  I've tried the following with no success..

```
.filter(( Q(something__gte=something) & Q(something__lte=something)) & ( Q(something__gte=something) & Q(something__lte=something)))

.filter( Q(something__gte=something,something__lte=something) & Q(something__gte=something,something__lte=something))
```

both returns the following.. and completely ignores my brackets...

```
WHERE (`something`.`something` >= something  AND `something`.`something` <= -something  AND `something`.`something` >= something  AND `something`.`something` <= something )
```

Comment: can't wait for downvotes on this one.. lol

Comment: Show us the actual query. You replaced a number of different identifiers with the same identifier (something) so we can't tell if you're doing it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the logical operator AND is associative.  a & b & c == (a & b) & c == a & (b & c).  No parentheses are needed

Comment: lol.. i just realized this two seconds ago.. had a brain fart.